# How to get responses and comment attachments with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on capturing Facebook page, event and group feeds with the Graph API. It's for a research project for my master studies. With these lines in the Graph API Explorer

{page-id}/feed?fields=from,message,likes,comments,attachments

I can capture the most I need. But the responses on comments and the attachments in comments (like when someone uses images in his or her comment) are still missing. How can I get them with the Graph API Explorer? It would be greet if I can get them within the whole context of the feed, not just when typing in the specific comment-id in the Graph API Explorer. Is there any way to get the needed data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/comments#read explains, it depends on the `filter` modifier whether you only get the top-level comments (`toplevel`, default), or all comments including replies (`stream`)

So if you modify your request as follows, you will get comments and replies on them in one go:

```
{page-id}/feed?fields=from,message,likes,comments.filter(stream),attachments
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But that will give you all comments on the same level in the data structure, so you won’t know which are replies – so you might want to request the `parent` property as well; for replies that holds the id of the parent comment. With

```
comments.filter(stream){parent,from,message,created_time}
```

you will also get the `parent` for comments that have one. (Once you’re asking for a specific field, you need to ask for the rest of the fields you want as well.)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Do you know any way for getting the attachments in comments, too?